# add heading just at first page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm designing a form to write a project report as below. I need to add a table at the top of first page, but not at other pages.
I've searched more, but i couldn't fine any related things. anyone can help me please?[image: photo of my work]

Comment: define special page style for the first page and than use for example as `\begin{document}\thispagestyle{myspecilapagestyleforthefirstpage} ...` where `myspecilapagestyleforthefirstpage` is the name of your style. of course you can change name to what you liked :)

Comment: Why don't you add the code you used to create that page style. This way we can see what you did and what to change.

Comment: as said @Skillmon, we don't know anything about your page style design. please, provide small but complete document by which we can test your solution, see design and after that we will be able to help you.

Comment: I added a photo from my work that i made it at Word 2013. But i'm not comfortable with Word. i'm kind of crazy about Latex. anyone can do that for me at latex or help me?

Comment: Why is it a header? Why not just a tabular at the top of the first page with no header material?